# export with jdk 8 still got error when start server

Tags: smartfoxserver

I used eclipse with jdk 8 to export to jar. Yet i still get this error when start my server sfs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sfs2x/extension/mmo/MMORoomDemoExtension$NPCData has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Could someone tell me how to fix.
I tried to uninstalled all java and install jdk8 only. But nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, what fixed it for me was making sure that jdk8 was selected as the build jdk for that project (right click on your project in Eclipse and click on properties -> Java build path -> JRE System Libraries -> Workspace Default JRE, make ure that jdk8 is selected) and then recompiling. I was able to delete all .class files before recompiling as well, but that may be difficult if this is a project.

Best of luck.

Comment: As you noticed me, i check and change  compiler from  11.0 to 1.8 like this: `project's properties` > `java compiler`>`enable project specific settings` > `compiler compliance level` > `change to 1.8`. Thank for your help.